# How to fix the garbled text in my text editors?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

When editing my nodes all of my saved data is displayed garbled. This is the warning I get on my node/edit pages: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."
The other odd part is that the contents of the database field and the contents of the output are correct. Just the contents of the text editor is garbled.
How can I fix this?

UPDATE: I have another content type that has a file field, and I have some pdfs loaded in those fields and those pdfs are the ones that are showing up in my text editor. Does anyone know why that would happen?

Comment: This looks like PDF data rather than HTML? How did you populate the content in these nodes?

Comment: I put my text into that field and then saved it. But when I went back in to edit the text it looked like that.

Comment: @Eluchel, If you put plain text in the editor and it turned into PDF data, looks like some other module behind the scenes messing with your node body data.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about looking for that module other than uninstalling modules one by one?

Comment: When you say you put your text into that field, how exactly did you do that? Did you paste it from a PDF?

Comment: I just type it in.

Comment: Look at `/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html` and see if there are any unusual Filters enabled. Also search in Modules to see if there are any PDF related modules enabled.

Comment: @Monkeybrain I looked at the text formats and I didn't see anything unusual (the only filter there that isn't in core is the collapsed text filter), I have looked through my modules and didn't see anything that looked like it it was PDF related. Other than uninstalling the modules one by one is there any way to find out which module it is?

Also, I think that the garbled text in the text editors is a BLOB from my cache_field table in my database. I updated my question to reflect this. Does that clarify what the problem might be?

Comment: Hi @Eluchel, sorry but I haven't seen this kind of problem before. What happens if you flush all Drupal caches?

Comment: Hey @Monkeybrain, no problem, I haven't ever either. 
When I clear the caches occasionally the first text field in the field group will clear up until I refresh, but all the others will still e trying to display the pdf. 

Oh, my most recent comment about the BLOBs was incorrect. The PDFs are coming from one of my other content types which has a file field.

Comment: Is it getting saved to the db like that or is it a render issue? `dpm(debug_backtrace());` Should help figure out the culprit although it can get messy so you might want to narrow it at least a little first.

Comment: It is not being saved to the database like that. Whatever I put in the feels is being saved correctly, it must be a render issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with aGov distro. I had to swapped from ckeditor module to WYSIWYG module + ckeditor lib.

That fixed the issue with ckeditor. However, today I got the garbled text again while having batched processes running which preventing them to complete. Thinking back, I realised the problem started when I installed Devel themer & simplehtmldom API (7.x-1.12). Uninstalling simplehtmldom fixed the issue for me.